# Iterated Integral With Odd Upper-Bound

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,1]$.  I would like to compute the following integral but I believe that I may be wrong when applying Fubini's theorem
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\int_0^{\sqrt{v}} f(u)dudv.
$$

Here's what I have computed (using the change of variables formulate formula and Fubini I "computed" that)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\int_0^{\sqrt{v}} f(u)dudv = &
\int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\int_0^{v} f(\sqrt{u}) \frac1{2\sqrt{u}}dudv\\
= &
\int_0^{t} \int_0^{\sqrt{u}}f(\sqrt{v}) \frac1{2\sqrt{v}}dvdu\\
= &
\frac1{2}\int_0^{t} \int_0^{u}f(\sqrt{\sqrt{v}}) \frac1{\sqrt{\sqrt{v}}} \frac1{2\sqrt{v}}dvdu\\
= &
\frac1{4}\int_0^{t} \int_0^{u}f(\sqrt[4]{v}) v^{-\frac{3}{4}}dvdu.
\end{aligned}
$$
Is this correct?  I feel as though something fishy happened when interchanging the integrals wrt. the bounds of integration.

Comment: Since the integrals have no dependence on $v$, why not reduce it to $\sqrt{t}$ times a single integral over $u$?

Comment: On your work, I cannot follow it. For example your first substitution seems to be missing a factor of $2$: $$ \int_0^{\sqrt{t}}f(u)du=\int_0^{t}\frac{f(\sqrt{w})}{2\sqrt{w}}dw$$

Comment: Even putting in the factor of 2, I cannot follow your second equal sign at all. Are you trying to do multiple steps at once, such as doing an operation and then deciding to randomly switch the names of your variables? It is easier to read if you only do one step at a time.

Comment: @Michael  Hi, I clarified some of the notation, I wanted second to depend on the first and I added a couple steps.  Let me know if it's better.

Comment: It seems you also changed the problem from $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}}$ to $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^\sqrt{v}$. Nevertheless I still cannot follow your second equation, how do you justify that? It looks like you are randomly swapping $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I think I have forgotten how to interchange integral to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem here:

> $$
> \int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\int_0^{v} f(\sqrt{u}) \frac1{2\sqrt{u}}dudv
> = 
> \int_0^{t} \int_0^{\sqrt{u}}f(\sqrt{v}) \frac1{2\sqrt{v}}dvdu
> $$

The region of integration is the triangle whose vertices are $(u=0,v=0)$, $(u=0,v = \sqrt{t})$, and $(u=\sqrt{t},v=\sqrt{t})$. To cover this triangle using the other order of integration, you have to integrate $v$ from $u$ to $\sqrt{t}$, then $u$ from $0$ to $\sqrt{t}$. Additionally, $f$ is still a function of $u$ regardless of the order of integration. So you should have
\begin{multline}
\int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\!\!\!\int_0^{\sqrt{v}}\! f(u)dudv = \int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\!\!\!\int_0^{v}\! \frac{ f(\sqrt{u})}{2\sqrt{u}}dudv
= 
\int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\!\!\!\int_u^{\sqrt{t}}\!\frac{f(\sqrt{u}) }{2\sqrt{u}}dvdu \\ = 
\int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\!\frac{f(\sqrt{u}) }{2\sqrt{u}}\left[\int_u^{\sqrt{t}}\!dv\right]du = \int_0^{\sqrt{t}}\!\frac{f(\sqrt{u})}{2\sqrt{u}}(\sqrt{t}-u)du = \int_0^{t^{1/4}}\!f(x)(\sqrt{t}-x^2)dx
\end{multline}

And here's [an example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B(x*Exp%5Bx%5D)(Sqrt%5Bt%5D-x%5E2),+%7Bx,+0,+t%5E(1%2F4)%7D%5D+%3D%3D+++Integrate%5Bu*Exp%5Bu%5D,+%7Bv,+0,+Sqrt%5Bt%5D%7D,+%7Bu,+0,+Sqrt%5Bv%5D%7D%5D) showing the equality of the two integrals.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Actually, the question here is a special case of the following:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290127/cauchy-repreated-integral-formula-with-root-upper-bounds

Comment: @N00ber : Eyeballfrog's point **Additionally, $f$ is still a function of $u$ regardless of the order of integration** nicely identifies the main issue in that second equality you wrote. It may be a helpful reminder to note that (under the mild conditions required for Fubini-Tonelli) we have $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(u,v)du\right]dv = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(u,v)dv\right]du$$ and in your case $g(u,v) = f(u) 1_{\{(u,v):0<v<\sqrt{t}, 0<u<\sqrt{v}\}}$.  **In particular we keep it as $g(u,v)$ and do not write $g(v,u)$.**

Comment: True, thank you very much Michael.  This helped alot also.